# jQuery dataTables type based column filtering not working? Img alt filter/sort

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Loving dataTables thus far, but just one problem I've run into...

I have a column of 'status' images styled as:

```
<td><img class="status" alt="green" src="images/dt/greenStatus.png"></td>
```

The column has a sType of 'alt-status' and I've added a custom sort to the column to sort them based on whether the alt text is  red, yellow, or green. It works perfect and as expected. Here's that code:

```
jQuery.extend( jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
    "alt-status-pre": function ( a ) {
        switch(a.match(/alt="(.*?)"/)[1].toLowerCase()){
            case 'green': return 1;
            case 'yellow': return 2;
            case 'red': return 3;
            default: return 4;
        }
    },

    "alt-status-asc": function( a, b ) {
        return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));     
    },

    "alt-status-desc": function(a,b) {
        return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0));
    }
} );
```

Now, I would like to only filter them based on this alt field as well. I tried a few different things but none of them work. I tried:

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.ofnSearch['alt-status'] = function ( sData ) {
    console.log(sData);
    return sData.replace(/\n/g," ").replace( /<.*?>/g, "" );
};
```

just to try and remove the html from the filter, but that didnt work either. I can still search for `<img`  and they all show.

From what I can tell, this method isn't even being called. Anyone have any experience with filtering based on image alt text?

This question was also posted on the dataTable forums: http://goo.gl/79XXq

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do this is now to use mData rather than ofnSearch. See: http://datatables.net/usage/columns#mData